# Found duplicate classes, falling back to extracting from APK

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I tried to migrate my code, into new one, i changed the file, classes, etc. But i just found out when i used the geolocator permission, i had this bug :

```
W/alesapp_pss_ap(17478): ClassLoaderContext type mismatch. expected=PCL, found=DLC (DLC[];PCL[base.apk*3410441305:base.apk!classes2.dex*1711013123:base.apk!classes3.dex*509358830:base.apk!classes4.dex*3747775487:base.apk!classes5.dex*3250956827:base.apk!classes6.dex*1212154329:base.apk!classes7.dex*4198662590:base.apk!classes8.dex*2376925184:base.apk!classes9.dex*1656733183:base.apk!classes10.dex*3789540358]{PCL[/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar*1452144318]#PCL[/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar*1128910120]#PCL[/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar*4177849200]#PCL[/system_ext/framework/androidx.window.sidecar.jar*709954415]#PCL[/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar*1452144318]} | DLC[];DLC[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000014/dl-MapsCoreDynamite.integ_234910200100700.apk*1682947577:/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000014/dl-MapsCoreDynamite.integ_234910200100700.apk!classes2.dex*759856134])
W/alesapp_pss_ap(17478): Found duplicate classes, falling back to extracting from APK : /data/app/~~yKkh81KArm3tNk_F14ZS0g==/com.google.android.gms-PN_TUYkex1XNcfxq-Ogpqw==/split_GoogleCertificates.apk
W/alesapp_pss_ap(17478): NOTE: This wastes RAM and hurts startup performance.
W/alesapp_pss_ap(17478): Found duplicated class when checking oat files: 'Landroid/support/annotation/Keep;' in /data/app/~~yKkh81KArm3tNk_F14ZS0g==/com.google.android.gms-PN_TUYkex1XNcfxq-Ogpqw==/split_GoogleCertificates.apk and /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000014/dl-MapsCoreDynamite.integ_234910200100700.apk
```

Here is my build.gradle on the android level

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1")
    }
    
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my build.gradle on the app level

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.salesapp_pss"
    //namespace "com.example.salesapp_pss_api"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.salesapp_pss_api"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

I tried to copy the project on the new flutter files, but it demanded to upgrade the ext.kotlin_version, which i dont found on my build.gradle, i added the buildscript on my gradle,and added to the latest kotlin version, but still error